# Duplicate UILabel with Content and slide out one right & one left

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton, uilabel

I'm new to objective-c and don't have an idea how to solve this problem. I guess I need to code this with my button which calls the label and changes the labels' text. Anybody an idea how to animate the funFactLabel.text that way that the (old) text slides out and a (new) text slides in when the button is clicked? Any help is welcome!

```
- (IBAction)showFunFact:(UIButton *)sender {

    // ease of facts
   funFactLabel.text = [self.factBook randomFact];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to make the old text slide out and the new text slide in is to create a second label and remove it when the animation is completed:

```
UILabel *oldLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:funFactLabel.frame];
[funFactLabel.superview addSubview:oldLabel];
oldLabel.text = funFactLabel.text;
// TODO: Configure oldLabel to match funFactLabel's font, colors, etc.

funFactLabel.text = [self.factBook randomFact];
funFactLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(funFactLabel.frame, funFactLabel.superview.bounds.size.width, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    funFactLabel.frame = oldLabel.frame;
    oldLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(oldLabel.frame, -oldLabel.superview.bounds.size.width, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [oldLabel removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

If you don't need a sliding animation, you can use UIView's transitionWithView method and one of Apple's built-in animations to do something similar without needing to make a second label:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:funFactLabel duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    funFactLabel.text = [self.factBook randomFact];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: First one working great! Really thanks for your help. The only issue remaining is that the label changes the size when its sliding out. Do you know how to solve this? @Dklionsk

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can you be more specific? To clarify, `oldLabel` is supposed to look identical to the original `funFactLabel` at the start of the animation, and `funFactLabel` is given the new text and moved to wherever it should start its animation (I guessed the right side of the screen). Then `oldLabel` slides to the left as `funFactLabel` with the new text slides in from the right, taking its place.

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain it. Something with the oldLabel is changing and makes the label always a little smaller. I don't know what it is at the moment I'm just trying to figure out what. Maybe you know where the issue is.   '  oldLabel.font = funFactLabel.font;
  oldLabel.textColor = funFactLabel.textColor;
  oldLabel.textAlignment = funFactLabel.textAlignment;
  oldLabel.numberOfLines = funFactLabel.numberOfLines;
  oldLabel.minimumScaleFactor  = funFactLabel.minimumScaleFactor;
  oldLabel.lineBreakMode = funFactLabel.lineBreakMode;
  oldLabel.layoutMargins = funFactLabel.layoutMargins;'

Comment: now i know its moving just a little to the left bevor the animation starts.

Comment: Can you include a link to the code, e.g. with https://gist.github.com/? Basically you should be making sure that (1) whatever special properties you set on funFactLabel you also set on oldLabel and (2) after you set oldLabel's frame to match funFactLabel's frame you don't modify it again before the animation.

Comment: [Link to the Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b713f6453c895c20b60) I've created the link to the code.

Comment: Did you set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on either label? You can also try adding background colors to the labels' frames to see how they change when the animation starts.

Comment: Yes i have it now. i have added some colors and solved the problem. Thank you very much!